# TikZ intersection clip

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to clip the parts of the circle inside the rectangle, I make to intersection points (c) and (d). but how can I clip the part inside the triangle between those two points (c) and (d)?

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [name path = zero,dashed](0,0) rectangle(15,15);
 \node[circle,fill=black] at (0,7.5) {};
  \node[circle,fill=black] at (7.5,0) {};
   \node[circle,fill=black] at (15,7.5) {};
    \node[circle,fill=black] at (7.5,15) {};
\draw (11.2,-0.35)--(11.2,0.35);
\draw (11.3,-0.35)--(11.3,0.35);

\draw (14.65,3.7)--(15.35,3.7);
\draw (14.65,3.8)--(15.35,3.8);
\draw [name path =one](0,7.5) circle (7.5); 
\draw [name path =two](7.5,0) circle (7.5); 
\draw [name path =three](15,7.5) circle (7.5); 
\draw [name path =four](7.5,15) circle (7.5);
\draw [name intersections={of=one and zero}] ;
  \coordinate (c)  at (intersection-1);
  \coordinate (d)  at (intersection-2);
    \clip ???
\draw [name intersections={of=three and zero}] ;
\coordinate (a)  at (intersection-1);
\coordinate (b)  at (intersection-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! So you want to have the half circles outside of the square?

Comment: I can't figure out from your question what exactly is meant to be clipped? Do you want only the parts of the two circles between `(c)` and `(d)`? So you'd have a single leaf-like shape for those two circles. Also, what do you want to clip to that shape? You cannot clip something you've already drawn.

Comment: Please clarify, a [triangle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triangle) is defined by *three* points. Given two points, it is pretty unclear, what parts of which circles should be removed.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to clip anything if you don't draw it in the first place.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset
  {dot/.style={circle,fill=black},
   doublelines/.style={double,very thick,double distance=1mm}
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed](0,0) rectangle(15,15);
\node[dot] at (0,7.5) {};
\node[dot] at (7.5,0) {};
\node[dot] at (15,7.5) {};
\node[dot] at (7.5,15) {};
\draw[doublelines] (11.25,-0.35)--(11.25,0.35);
\draw[doublelines] (14.65,3.75)--(15.35,3.75);
\draw (0,0)
  arc (270:  90:7.5)
  arc (180:   0:7.5)
  arc ( 90: -90:7.5)
  arc (  0:-180:7.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another solution is to draw the circles first and the rectangle second, and to fill the rectangle in white.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset
  {dot/.style={circle,fill=black},
   doublelines/.style={double,very thick,double distance=1mm}
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,7.5)  circle (7.5); 
\draw (7.5,0)  circle (7.5); 
\draw (15,7.5) circle (7.5); 
\draw (7.5,15) circle (7.5);
\draw[dashed,fill=white] (0,0) rectangle(15,15);
\node[dot] at (0,7.5) {};
\node[dot] at (7.5,0) {};
\node[dot] at (15,7.5) {};
\node[dot] at (7.5,15) {};
\draw[doublelines] (11.25,-0.35)--(11.25,0.35);
\draw[doublelines] (14.65,3.75)--(15.35,3.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```